# How to show an entire function bounded on a sequence of concentric annuli is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a problem from a past PhD Prelim Exam in Complex Analysis: 
Let $f$ be an entire function and suppose that
$$|f(z)| \leq \left|f\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right|+ \frac{1}{2^n}$$ whenever $2^n\leq |z|\leq2^{n+1}$. Prove that $f$ is constant function. 
I think I should use Liouville's theorem for this. Here's my idea: $f$ is bounded for $|z|\leq 1$, and for $|z|>1$, there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^n\leq |z|\leq2^{n+1}$;  but I'm not sure how to proceed with this to show the boundedness of f.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: A naive idea is to over the complex plane by a sequence of annuli. Since $\sum_{n\ge1}\dfrac{1}{2^n}=1$ (converges), and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\dfrac{z}{2^n}\right)=f(0)$ this trick will work for your problem.

Comment: The only thing left to check before applying Liouville is that $f$ is bounded. First, $f$ is bounded on the unit closed disk, say by $M_0$. Then see what the bound $M_n$ on $2^n \leq |z|\leq 2^{n+1}$ is in terms of $\{M_k \mid k=0,\ldots n-1\}$. Argue that the sequence $(M_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is bounded.

Comment: @EricTowers Noted and corrected, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all your contributions!